# The eigenvalue of $B=\mathrm{Re\ }A$ for $A$ a Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a Hermitian matrix, $B=\mathrm{Re\ }A$, i.e. real part of $A$, how to prove that $$\max \lambda\leq \max\mu$$ where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of $B$, $\mu$ is the eigenvalue of $A$.

---

It can be noted that $B$ is also Hermitian, and can be written as $\frac{A+\overline{A}}{2}$.

Comment: Maybe try using the Rayleigh quotient to get your bound...I'm still thinking about this, so I am not entirely sure...

Answer (score 2):

Let $\rho(A)$ denote the spectral radius of a matrix $A$.  I’m going to assume that you really wanted to show $\rho(B)\le\rho(A)$ rather than $\max \lambda\leq \max\mu$, since otherwise the assertion is false in general.

It's easy to show that $\rho \left( B \right) \le \left\| B \right\|$ for any square matrix $B$ and matrix norm.  For Hermitian matrices and for the spectral norm in particular, we have that $\rho \left( A \right) = \left\| A \right\|_2.$  Therefore, the result follows from a basic application of the triangle inequality to $\left\|B\right\|_2=\left\|\frac{A+\overline{A}}{2}\right\|_2.$